# semi transparent div in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, transparency

Hey am developing a website where i want to display a div with a semi transparent background so that the page background is visible.
i want this to work on all browsers.
am fine using CSS , JS or jquery...
please give me suggestions and if possible some sample code..

Thanks in advance,
Raj

Answer (score 9):

Probably your best bet is to use pure CSS. This technique works on Safari 3.2+, IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.05+, Chrome 4+, and Opera 10+

```
div {
  /* black for browsers which cannot support rgba */
  background-color: #000;

  /* 70% opacity for supported browsers */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

  /* IE 5.5+ support #BB000000 is ~70% opacity on black */
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
    startColorstr=#BB000000, endColorstr=#BB000000
  );

  /* IE 8 support */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
    startColorstr=#BB000000, endColorstr=#BB000000
  )";
}
```

Comment: The parts hacked in for IE made me wince >_< Sooo ugly and overly complicated compared to the simple CSS counterparts.  I wish the IE developers would err... open their eyes and realize the pain web developers are facing, to get compatibility for their application.

Comment: So true, but having the option is super nice, as opposed to fudging around with PNG's + pngfix for IE anyways... :)

Comment: Or if you're like me, and you're working with your own personal projects for fun, you can just sit back and say "Screw IE" ^_^

Answer (score 2):

For CSS compliant browsers: Element.style.opacity = decimal from 0-1
For IE [aka, the devil] : element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity="+(Number from 0-100)+")"

Examples on: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp

Note that text/content in the div will become semi-transparent as well.

Example which sets the opacity of a div to 50%:

```
var myElement = document.body.getElementById("elemId");
myElement.style.opacity = 0.5;
myElement.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=50)"; //For the devil, IE
```

By the way, 1 [or in the case of IE, 100] is Totally visible, while 0 is totally transparent.

Hope that helps! ;-)

Comment: So you are just writing the CSS with JavaScript? Why not just write the CSS in the first place?

Comment: He said he was fine with using JS.  In my case, I don't work much with the "classic" elements, such as div, span, whatever.  I've been playing with canvas exclusively.  Because of this, I don't really use stylesheets anymore.  Since I work with JavaScript so much, I find it messy if i have a ton of CSS and a ton of JavaScript all over, messing with the style of an element.  Of course, if you're designing a static-ish website, using the <style> tag is fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `opacity` the *entire* div, including the text, will be at that opacity level.

If your visitors are using a Webkit (Chrome, Safari) or Gecko (Firefox) browser (possibly Presto (Opera), too, but I'm not sure) then you could use:

`#divToMakePartiallyOpaque {background-color: rgba(150,150,150,0.5); }`

Wherein the red, green and blue channels are set to `150` and the alpha is set to `0.5` (halfway between fully transparent and fully opaque).

There's also the possibility of using a partially-transparent background-image, as noted elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a semi-transparent PNG.  IE 6 does not support semi-transparency as far as I know, but I believe IE7+ and the rest of the mainstream browsers do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with a jQuery solution, the following will work for all browsers that jQuery supports (Firefox 2.0+, Internet Explorer 6+, Safari 3+, Opera 9+, Chrome 1+):

```
$('div').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Elmo saids or:

```
opacity= .5; 
filter:Alpha(opacity=50);  
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```